# How can I access the external microphone with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, microphone, alsa

Sound in Ubuntu, it has its own special joy.  I would like my external microphone to work.

Symptoms:

- I can play sound through the speakers
- I can play sound through the headsets.
- Plugging and and plugging headphone output correctly switches.
- I can record from the built-in microphone, using "Sound Recorder" and others.

but:

- I cannot record from the external microphone.
- My Sound Preferences/Input panel has no option for an external microphone.

If the answer is upgrade the ALSA drivers, please say exactly what to type.

Thank you.

========

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala on a laptop (Gateway W3501), Sigmatel.

That is:

```
~$ head -1 /proc/asound/card0/code*
==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
Codec: SigmaTel STAC9205

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#1 <==
Codec: Conexant ID 2c06
~$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I looked at the [ALSA website](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Help_To_Debug_Intel_HDA), because the sound drivers ship out of sync with the usual Ubuntu upgrades.  For Intel HDA especially, the recommendation is to install alsamixer and then go playing with settings.

```
$ sudo apt-get install alsamixer
$ alsamixer
```

Then I found that the default settings for "Digital Input Source" is incorrect.  It should be "Analog".

Comment: Where do you see `"Digital Input Source"` in `alsamixer`? I'm running v 1.1.3, when I start it the default sound card has one master and one capture potentiometer. When I select the sound card `HD Audio Generic` which is a Realtek ALC256, then I see two separate Mic Boost potentiometers and when I adjust one the other follows as well. But I don't see where to select the input source and I cannot access my external mic. This is an ASCII graphic program just to be clear.